# CSS hover issue (overlay)

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with CSS. All I need is to let my image overlay other images on hover, but save positions of all images. For now it looks like that.

[image: that]

For my purposes, I need to save all positions even positions of images I am trying to `:hover`.

```
.image-design {
  width: 215px;
  height:250px;
  margin-Top:8px;
  margin-Left:8px;                
  margin-Right:8px;
  outline: solid 1.5px #FC5185;
  transition: outline 0.6s linear;
}
.image-design:hover {
  outline-width: 5px;
  outline-color: rgb(119, 230, 245);
  background: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Its close to what I want, but my flexbox pulling image from second row to first row, and now on the screen only 11 images (12 at start)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the width and height of the image on hover but add scaling:

```
.image-design:hover {
  outline-width: 5px;
  outline-color: rgb(119, 230, 245);
  background: cover;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, there is room to upgrade that, but much obliged for giving me a direction